# How do you remove a schema lock on a dbf file accessed using ArcObjects?

Tags: gis, arcgis, arcobjects

I am creating a custom geoprocessing tool for ArcGIS Desktop/Server.  During the tool execution, I create a dbf file and access its contents using a cursor.  The lock on this file remains after the tool has finished executing and can only be removed by restarting ArcMap/ArcCatalog.  Is there a programmatic method to remove the schema lock?

I have stepped into the code below, line by line.  Creation of the ITable ArcObject creates a lock file ending in ".sr.lock" and creating the ICursor object creates a lock file ending in ".rd.lock" in the same directory as the dbf file.  Without using either ReleaseComObject method at the bottom, both files persist.  I can get the second lock file from the cursor removed but not the one associated with the table.  Even if I delete the dbf file, the lock files persist, and the parent directory cannot be deleted until ArcMap/ArcCatalog is closed.

There is code [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/how-do-i-remove-schema-locks-from-a-file-geodatabase-in-java-in-arcgis-9-3) that hints at a solution, but there are elements of that code that are missing.

```
    public Dictionary<Int32, Dictionary<Int32,Double>> GetTabulatedAreaDict()
    {
        IGPUtilities3 gpUtil = new GPUtilitiesClass();
        Geoprocessor gp = new Geoprocessor();

        //Tabulate Area
        string tableName = "lcAreaByRru.dbf";
        string tablePath = this.tempDirPath + "\\" + tableName;
        TabulateArea tabulateArea = new TabulateArea();
        tabulateArea.in_zone_data = this.rruPath;
        tabulateArea.zone_field = "VALUE";
        tabulateArea.in_class_data = this.rasterValue.GetAsText();
        tabulateArea.class_field = "VALUE";
        tabulateArea.out_table = tablePath;
        gp.Execute(tabulateArea, null);

        // Extract information from table
        IWorkspaceFactory wsf = new ShapefileWorkspaceFactoryClass();
        IWorkspace ws = wsf.OpenFromFile(this.tempDirPath, 0);
        IFeatureWorkspace fws = (IFeatureWorkspace)ws;
        ITable taTable = fws.OpenTable(tableName);// Creates .sr.lock file
        //ITable taTable = gpUtil.OpenTableFromString(tablePath); // Creates .sr.lock file
        ICursor tableRows = taTable.Search(null, false); // Creates .rd.lock file
        IRow tableRow = tableRows.NextRow();
        this.tabulatedAreaDict = new Dictionary<Int32, Dictionary<Int32, Double>>();
        while (tableRow != null)
        {
            Int32 id = (Int32)tableRow.get_Value(1); // Feature ID
            Dictionary<Int32, Double> valueAreaDict = new Dictionary<Int32, Double>();
            for (int i = 2; i < tableRow.Fields.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                int key = int.Parse(tableRow.Fields.get_Field(i).Name.Split('_')[1]);
                double value = (double)tableRow.get_Value(i);
                valueAreaDict.Add(key, value);
            }
            this.tabulatedAreaDict.Add(id, valueAreaDict);
            tableRow = tableRows.NextRow();
        }

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(tableRows); //Removes .rd.lock file
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(taTable); // Does not remove .sr.lock file

        return this.tabulatedAreaDict;
    }
```

Update:

I found that the dbf was not locked, but there were stray lock files associated with the dbf. While ArcCatalog was still running, I was able to delete the table, but I was not able to delete the folder containing the dbf. Deletion of the parent directory failed when using the ArcCatalog GUI or Windows Explorer. I was able to delete the folder using the Delete_management geoprocessing tool.

I had considered accessing the dbf using a non-ArcObjects method, but I realized I would probably run into this problem later with feature classes and geodatabases, so it was best to continue using ArcObjects.

To better manage this issue, I intend to create the table in the scratch workspace (system temp if unspecified) then move the file to the correct destination when I'm finished accessing it.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted doesn't look too different from what I usually do, but maybe you could try pulling the workspace factory and the geoprocessor to a more global level instead of instantiating them at every method call. I do remember running into some locking problems using the geoprocessor, so I try to avoid using it and working with arcobjects directly where possible.

You'll be better off asking this question at gis.stackexchange.com. I know of at least one ArcObjects guru frequenting that place.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try gis.stackexchange.com.  I had the geoprocessor at the class level, but I tried moving it within the method hoping it would help.  The locking is occurring on the use of ArcObject ITable, the dbf output from geoprocessor isn't locked.  If only ArcObjects that created locks had close() methods!

Comment: I found an existing question:   http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3580/problems-closing-dbf-table-edited-with-arcobjects/4731#4731